# Как задать в Яндекс-Картах iconImageSize при загрузке через ObjectManager?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

При добавление в JSON поля

```
option.iconImageSize=[100,100]
```

размер иконок не меняется.

Answer (score 1):

Не получается потому что нужно писать options, а не option. Посмотрите как устроены данные тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_spatial